# Make static content available through react-router

Tags: json, reactjs, react-router

I have a JavaScript file in my `create-react-app` app that looks like this:

```
export const products = 
[
    {
        ...
```

Which is essentially a JSON object that I use in various components. Now, I want to make that JSON object available as static content too since I'm using it in other apps outside this one so that when I go to `https://myapp.com/products.json` (I don't care too much about the extension actually) I would be able to retrieve the data. I have currently this in my `index.js`:

```
... various imports
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={withTracker(App)}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('root'))
```

I guess I need to add a new Route but how?

Comment: Static file serving needs to be configured on your node server, if you are using node

Comment: this is just a react app, no server once deployed